# Interpreting gprof result and granularity

Tags: c, profiling, gprof

I am using gprof for profiling a C program for the first time. The following lines appears in the report that I generated using;

```
 $  gprof test_gprof gmon.out > analysis.txt
```

In Flat Profile

> Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.

is this the maximum resolution in time?

In call graph:

> granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) for 7.69% of 0.13
>   seconds

What exactly is 4 bytes here ? and what time it is talking about?

Comment: Have you read this: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_chapter/gprof_5.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read charpter 5.1 and 5.2 of this [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/index.html#Top). You can also read this manual on CentOS with the following command:

```
$ info gprof
```

In Flat Profile,

> Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.

indicates that the sampling period is 100Hz, which is not controlled by gprof itself(Check this [page](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2004-05/msg00505.html) and this [one](http://binutils.sourceware.narkive.com/Qfwc5miT/help-change-the-sampling-time-in-gprof) for more details). Therefore, `0.01 seconds` is theoretically not the maximum resolution in time.

As for Call graph, according to this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/wrkshp50/805-4947/6j4m8jrn7/index.html) from Oracle,

> The "4 bytes" means resolution to a single instruction. The "0.07% of 14.74 seconds" means that each sample, representing ten milliseconds of CPU time, accounts for 0.07% of the run.